# Is int an undocumented alias for numeric?

Tags: oracle, plsql

This code runs without any errors:

```
DECLARE
  files int(5);
BEGIN
  SELECT count(*) 
    INTO files 
    FROM o.DEPART;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (files);
END;
/
```

Is `int` an undocumented alias for numeric?

Comment: No, it is documented - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/datatypes.htm#i10924

Answer (score 3):

`int` is a synonym for `integer` - ANSI SQL data type. If you look at the declaration of the `standard` package, you'll see that the `integer` is simply a subtype of `number` data type declared as

```
subtype INTEGER is NUMBER(38,0);
```

Simply put, `int` is a constrained `number` data type, which allows you, as it name implies, to store integers only.

[Oracle ANSI SQL data types](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF55584)